# Git merge updated WordPress plugins

Tags: git, merge, wordpress

I have a few WordPress plugins which required updates. I know that there were changes  to the plugin files made by myself and others which would be overwritten by updating the plugins. I don't know where all changes were made since other people made some of them.

I updated plugins and pushed them to a separate branch. So, I had the master branch with all the changes made to the plugins, and an updated branch which overwrote those changes. I merged both branches together and there were no conflicts.

Am I right to think that the changes previously made to the plugin files have been successfully merged with the updates or is it likely I lost some of them?

The git branches look something like this:

```
           -----Updated Plugins----
          /                        \
         /                          \
------Master-----------------------Merged Branch----
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the plugin have been successfully merged.

If changes from others would have overlapped with changes made by you, you would have had conflicts to solve (which it's not the case, as you said).

Since you updated the master branch with the changes made by others, and then merged yours, now merged master branch have both changes in it.

You can always check the commit logs to see where changes from other people were.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks. I expected as much but I just wanted a second look to make sure I wasn't messing something up.